# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar data de mi base de datos en un gráfico usando Laravel 6.0 junto con Google Charts?

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema con Google Charts y Laravel 6.0, al hacer el gráfico no me muestra ningun error.. pero tampoco puedo visualizar el gráfico.. Esta es mi función

```
public function index()
{

$data = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->select(
    DB::raw('requiere_rep as requiere_rep'),
    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
    ->groupBy('requiere_rep')
    ->get();
    $array[] = ['Requiere_rep', 'Number'];
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $array[++$key] = [$value->requiere_rep, $value->number];
}
    return view('Incidencias.index')->with('requiere_rep', json_encode($array));
}
```

Este es el Script donde tengo todo lo necesario para que se muestre el gráfico en la pantalla.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var analytics = <?php echo $requiere_rep; ?>
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
               { calc: "stringify",
                 sourceColumn: 1,
                 type: "string",
                 role: "annotation" },
               2]);

var options = {
title: "TOP INCIDENCIAS POR CLIENTES",
width: 380,
height: 180,
bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
legend: { position: "none" },
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
chart.draw(view, options);

</script>
```

Y por último mi HTML, obvie todo lo demás y coloque la etiqueta para mostrar el gráfico.

```
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; margin-top: 10%; margin-left: -431%;"></div>
```

Estoy intentando mostrar un gráfico tipo barras, gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo de esta manera, por si a caso alguien lo necesita

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var analytics = <?php echo $requiere_rep; ?>

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
var options = {
title : 'INCIDENCIAS POR REGIONES'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, de ese modo los demás sabremos que está es ma solución